# Formula to return fastest speed by driver is a list of drivers and speeds

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need an Excel formula that will look at driver number is column A (as compared to driver roster list) and return the fastest time in column B for that particular driver.  For Example, sheet A list all drivers and times in columns A & B:

```
A 150.00
B 175.00
C 150.50
A 156.00
C 151.00
```

The next sheet has all drivers listed

```
A John Doe
B Steve Smith
C Mike Johnson
```

I need the third column to look at the first sheet and wherever the driver is the same as column A on sheet two, it returns the highest value.  So, for driver A, it needs to return 156.00, and for driver B, 175.00.

Answer (score 1):

Use following formula to returns max speed of driver "A":

```
=MAX(IF(Sheet1!A:A="A",Sheet1!B:B))
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

You can change hardcoded "A" to any cell reference, say `A1` as in image below:

[image]